# react-router -> Create route without shared HTML from AppComponent

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new in React and I'm having some specific issue with react-router. So let's have a look at it:

**What I have:**

```
// App.tsx
<Router history={history}>
  <div id="app" className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <Header />
    <div className="flex-grow-1 mt-md-5">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/invoice" component={Invoice} exact />
        <PrivateRoute path="/invoice/:id" component={InvoiceDetail} exact />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </div>
</Router>
```

**What I need:**

```
/invoice/${id}/print
```

however for print page I want to render specific HTML / CSS without things as `<Header>`. As you can imagine I want generate page which I just pass to some PDF creator.

I would expect this is not that rare thing to do but I didn't find any examples which suite my scenario. So any advise is more than welcome.

Comment: Moving your `/invoice/:id/print` to be the first `Route` inside the `Switch` would partially solve it. Now you just have to render `Header` inside the router too

Comment: Hey @Dupocas This will required some refactoring and also logically route belong to ```/invoice/:id/print``` so I bet it will work but I'm hoping for some sophisticated solution

Comment: What about matching `Header` to render on all paths except that one

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have nested switch statements, one w/ the header and one w/out

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <PrivateRoute path="/invoice/:id/print" component={InvoiceDetail} exact />
    <Route path="/" render={() => 
      <div id="app" className="d-flex flex-column h-100">
        <Header />
        <div className="flex-grow-1 mt-md-5">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/invoice" component={Invoice} exact />
            <PrivateRoute path="/invoice/:id" component={InvoiceDetail} exact />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div> 
    /> 
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Though I'd probably move the render function to its own component so it reads easier, but this should give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use another `<Switch>` to wrap your `<Header/>` and write a simple condition, it would like:

```
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/invoice/:id/print" render={() => null} />
    <PrivateRoute component={Header} />
</Switch>
```